# Git Versioning and Library Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, git, version-control

Please read both 1 and 2.  If you are not an Android dev you could still help because this is a versioning problem as well.

Here is the situation:

I have inherited an android project created in IntelliJ and am currently importing it into Eclipse.  But many obstacles lay in the way...

1. In IntelliJ Android Libraries can be sub-directories (children) of the project, however, in Eclipse you can only select Android Libraries that are in the current workspace (Siblings).  Is it possible to select a child directory?
2. If #1 cannot be fixed then how can I approach the following: I have an Android Library project that contains many reusable components (static utils).  Assume the Android Library is a sibling directory to the project.  I have a version 1 application that uses the Android Library.  I now create a version 2 that uses the Android Library but I also update the libraries API (change some methods).  Version 2 is in development and version 1 is being maintained.  When Eclipse cleans the projects the Android Library is no longer compatible with version 1 since the API has changed.

The project inherited was build in IntelliJ and the Android Library was a git repo and git submodules.  Thus the reference was to a git commit and the repo could be externally updated.  I essentially need to get versioning with Android Libraries working (I do not care about using or not using git submodules).  Anybody have a solution?

Comment: You should use eclipse tag as it is Eclipse related.

Comment: @LexLi Thx, there are many tags that could be used, just want a wide audience as its not specific to android :S

Answer (score 2):

The Answer for

In IntelliJ Android Libraries can be sub-directories (children) of the project, however, in Eclipse you can only select Android Libraries that are in the current workspace (Siblings). Is it possible to select a child directory?

> Yes it is possible to reference a child directory(Android Library
>   Project) in your Application project.

### Step 1: Add the library project's directory inside your Application project's root directory.

### Step2: Import this sub directory as a project in eclipse.

> `File` -> `Import`, Under `Android` select `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`, For `Root Directory` browse to the root directory of your
>   app project directory. In the list of Projects you get your own project plus the library
>   project i.e. the sub directory. **Make sure that only the library project is selected and not your App**. Hit `Finish`.

### Step 3: Reference to this library project.

> Go to your Application project's `Android properties` and add this
>   library project in the `library section`.

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks for step 3. I always searched in "Configurate Build Path" which opened "Java Build Path" but not "Android"